# What's the proper way to reload a UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

While I was working with ios apps suddenly one question struct in my mind. What if I want to reload whole view? What will happen if I invoke `viewDidLoad`?  Is that the right way to do this? I'm asking just for my knowledge only.

Comment: What do you mean `reload` the whole view, can you tell a bit more of what you are doing? You are more likely to attract downvotes and close -this-question with such general question. explain as much as you can, provide code, tell us what you have done, where you are stuck, what you want yada yada...

Answer (score 3):

If the view is the main view of some controller, you can reload it by setting the controller’s `view` property to `nil` – it will be loaded again the next time somebody uses the `view` property. Invoking `-viewDidLoad` would not work, it’s just a callback method called by some  `UIViewController` code when the view is finished loading.

Comment: Thanks zoul. But by setting controller's view property to nil will not reload the view.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't? Note that the view will not reload immediately, just the next time it's needed.

Comment: Ok. So is there any way to reload the view immediately, without loading its next time?

Comment: What you want doesn’t make much sense, but if you call `[controller setView:nil]; [controller view]`, the view will be reloaded immediately.

Comment: yes it does load viewdidload immediately but through this method I got only my viewdidload method is invoked. It doesn't affect on whole life cycle. For example I don't get my viewwillappear to be called.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? You appear to be doing something too complex, misusing the Cocoa code to do something that should be solved in a different way.

Comment: Yeah that's why I've asked this question for my reference only. Take a look at this -  Initially my app is ad enabled. But when I'll upgrade the app whole uiview will reload again with no ads. This is why I want to reload the UIView.

Comment: In that case you should redisplay the whole controller, like replace it with a different instance that has the ads turned off. Reloading just the view is a gross hack in this case.

Comment: Yes. I've already removed ads from my view when it is get upgraded.& want few changes from the begining of view life cycle.THat's why I need to reload it

Answer (score 2):

You may use following simple code to reload view.

```
[YOUR_VIEW setNeedsDisplay];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload the whole view, you can use `reloadInputViews` method or write the code in `viewWillAppear` , so everytime you make a new object of your viewController, the code in viewWillAppear will recall itself.

Comment: what do you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to reload the whole uiview life cycle

Comment: ok for what purpose? cuz may be your purpose can be solved without reloading the view...

Comment: OK. Initially my app is ad enabled. But when I'll upgrade the app whole uiview will reload again with no ads. This is why I want to reload the UIView.

Comment: so you can simply hide and show the Ad View.what is the need to reload whole view?

Comment: Instead of hiding ads .I've removed it from my view.I want to reload  view since I want some changes in newly loaded view.

Comment: yes you can remove it from the view and then make changes..without refreshing the whole view. and since i don't exactly know what you are trying to implement so i can't suggest further...